# Histogram from multiple raster in one graph in QGIS?

Tags: raster, qgis-3, histogram

I have more than 10 rasters which are actually MNDWI index images created from Landsat image. I want to visualize all rasters (tiff) files in one graph to understand the spectral distribution. Is there any plugin in QGIS to do that?

Comment: Did you try virtual raster?

Comment: You can write a python (pyqgis + matplotlib) code for that.

Comment: Wow this would be great function.

Comment: No i did not try virtual raster, and i wonder if there is any plugins for that!!